# System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException in WCF (Visual Studio 2017)

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf, ssl

I was new to web services domain. I was just writing a simple service using a tutorial. 
**The code for MyService.cs is as follows:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestService
 {
   class MyService : IMyService
   {
    public string GetData()
      {
        return "iamchiragsharma.website2.me";
      }
   }
 }
```

**and for the IMyService.cs is :**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace TestService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    interface IMyService
   {

    [OperationContract]
    string GetData();
   }
}
```

When I pressed **Start** button the following error showed up : [image]

**I have tried using the HTTP registration checking method and even the deleted and recreated the port but it was nothing of help.**

**I would like to know the reason of this error and it's fix?**  Any kind of help will be sincerely appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious possibility is that you have another process outside of Visual Studio that is running on port 8733 however I'm not convinced this is the issue here as I'm guessing you've let Visual Studio pick that port to use.

I remember reading about a similar issue that was resolved by running Visual Studio with elevated privileges (i.e. **Run as administrator**). This might be worth a try.

Comment: Hi there! I tried using the Run as administrator method but it gave the same output. I have nearly tried all the conventional methods still my problem is not resolved. If my app.config is needed I will provide it too.